# Supporting different screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, google-play, android-screen-support

I want to make game for supporting all Android device(Tablets and phones).I can get screen size through coding.
Do I have make 3 0r 4 layouts small , medium and large?
Which size for small , medium , large and extra large?
Is there any other way to set layout for all devices?

Comment: [**Let Me Google That For You**](http://bit.ly/MElEBc)

Comment: ^ sarcasm aside, your question is basically asking for a "brief overview of how to support multiple screens", so you really are better off just reading the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Android documentation for what you need:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

You can use the screen-size, screen pixel density, or other things to determine how to separate your layouts.

You can specify different layouts (and you should try to). Different sizes may use the same layout. What layout the device ends up using depends on a set of rules.

So for example if you wanted to use screen size, you would want to make folders under your res folder called layout-small, layout-medium, layout-large, layout-xlarge. This is because layout is the default folder for layout resources, and then you add a -. In this case, small, medium, large, or xlarge.

Edit: Alex's link above might be what you're looking for. My link is more about HOW to do it, but Alex's link is more about how to do it WELL. I wasn't sure what you were asking exactly.

Answer (score 0):

(1) One way to support all the layout sizes is to put images of suitable sizes into drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi and drawable-xhdpi. The image for a device of a particular screen size will be automatically picked by Android runtime system. In this approach you will NOT have to make different layout files for each size.

(2) Second way to achieve the same is to dynamically detect the size(density) of the device and then set the layout accordingly, which can be done like this:

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    switch(displayMetrics.densityDpi){ 
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW: 
            // your layout for small-size devices.
            break; 
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM: 
            // your layout for medium-size devices.
            break; 
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: 
            // your layout for big-size devices.
            break; 
    }
```

In this approach, you MAY have to make different layout files for each size separately.